# Route traffic between 2 networks

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I have 2 LANS:

- 172.16.0.0/24, named LAN_A
- 172.16.1.0/24, named LAN_B

I would like to make them talk to each other by adding a PC with 2 ethernet cards:

- eth0 has IP 172.16.0.1 and it is attached to the LAN_A
- eth1 has IP 172.16.1.1 and it is attached to the LAN_B
  from this machine I can ping both networks.
- From PCs in LAN_A I can ping/traceroute only up to eth0
- From PCs in LAN_B I can ping/traceroute only up to eth1

Is there a way to make these 2 networks see each other, please?
I am running a headless server edition 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You need to bridge the interfaces, easiest way is to use `bridge-utils` as per [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge):

**Install bridge-utils**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bridge-utils
```

**Backup /etc/network/interfaces**

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
```

**Bridge configuration**

Add this to your /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Bridge between eth0 and eth1
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

**Restart networking**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

To restore your initial configuration just restore interfaces.bak and restart networking service

```
yes "" | cp /etc/network/interfaces.bak /etc/network/interfaces
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```